# Cassandra :: Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0x7acf3f0c, L:/100.55.10.124:9042 ! R:/30.75.50.2:39263]

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using Cassandra 3.10 with 6 Nodes cluster having replication Factor 2.  [please consider the IP's have been masked and not original].

```
Datacenter: DC1
===========================================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  100.55.10.124  212.33 MiB  256          65.9%             8328123a-678c-4027-a136-06b3626ab017  rack1
UN  100.55.10.125  216.92 MiB  256          67.1%             af76123c-6880-43d6-bff8-b139731242bd  rack1
UN  100.55.10.126  216.94 MiB  256          67.0%             f541cdc1-aa2f-4a30-3612-5d4291421ec3  rack1
Datacenter: DC2
===========================================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  100.55.10.130  198.15 MiB  256          60.7%             332eb914-bf14-4d0d-9c38-47fc4b0952f1  rack2
UN  100.55.10.131  229.48 MiB  256          70.8%             cafc702f-83d4-479a-b117-ada75274e0ba  rack2
UN  100.55.10.132  223.14 MiB  256          68.5%             8a9c03ae-ed5a-4cb9-9540-0ca97a04640e  rack2
```

cluster was working fine, but these days i see below "INFO" in the system logs

```
INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2017-04-19 03:21:19,684 Message.java:617 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0x7acf3f0c, L:/100.55.10.124:9042 ! R:/30.75.50.2:39263]
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: syscall:read(...)() failed: Connection reset by peer
        at io.netty.channel.unix.FileDescriptor.readAddress(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
```

I was trying to analyze the issue, but couldn't make it yet. 

 
i've looked at following [JIRA issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11128) around this, but wasn't able to find anything helpful.
i've also referred to few stackoverflow links couldnt find anything conclusive.

[Unexpected exception during request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477913/unexpected-exception-during-request)

[Cassandra Timeouts with No CPU Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708258/cassandra-timeouts-with-no-cpu-usage)

[Strange exception in /var/log/cassandra/system.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342719/strange-exception-in-var-log-cassandra-system-log)

i am using CQL v3.4.4. Is there anyone, who is familiar with above scenario?

Comment: An old post, but solved same issue, this is because of a client application on IP 30.75.50.2 is closing/kiling connection with Cassandra node. This will cause the same INFO message.

Answer (score 1):

As this request is showing "Native-Transport-Requests" in that case would request to check the output of "nodetool tpstasts" command.

If you see a high blocked count on "Native-Transport-Requests" in that case you  plan to increase max_queued_native_transport_requests.

CQL Native Protocol is the way the Cassandra driver communicates with the server. This includes all reads, writes, schema changes, etc. There are a limited number of threads available to process incoming requests.

When all threads are in use, some requests wait in a queue (pending). If the queue fills up, some requests are silently rejected (blocked) and the server never replies.

https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/360031470531-High-blocked-NTR-count-during-increased-workload-on-Cassandra-node